# ASP.NET CORE Web API with Swagger produces wrong property names

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.0

So I set up a new Solution with an API. This API is working as expected as you can see in the following postman request:

```
{
 "Id": 1,
 "Name": "Samsung"
}
```

Swagger produces this piece of code:

```
{
 "id": 0,
 "name": "string"
}
```

This code snippets are showing a Brand from my Model.

> How can I fix it so that Swagger takes the property names as shown in the first code snippet ?

This is how i configured the API and the Model:

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<PhoneCalculatorContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger(c => c.SerializeAsV2 = true);

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Model:

```
public class Brand
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: is lower casing? this is the default now in dotnet to get in line with rest standards

Comment: Can you add a print of where swagger is showing this:

Comment: @saj I did not know that it is a REST standard to write the given data in lower case, therefore i guess the whole question is irrelevant and I should just use it with lower case ?

Answer (score 0):

You could custom `ISchemaFilter` to show the custom example value like below:

1.Custom `ISchemaFilter`

```
public class AddSchemaExamples : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiModel.Type == typeof(Brand))
        {
            // TODO: Set the example.
            schema.Example = new OpenApiObject
            {
                ["Id"] = new OpenApiInteger(1),
                ["Name"] = new OpenApiString("Samsung")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

2.Regster `ISchemaFilter`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.SchemaFilter<AddSchemaExamples>();
});
```

3.Result:
[image]